# If you want to describe ajax , what would you say?

Tags: ajax

I know that there are lots to read on the net about AJAX , but if U want to explained it for a non-web-technical person what would you say ?

Comment: Allows web apps to be just as rich and interactive as a smart / fat client app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A style of web page where you can edit stuff without having to wait for the whole page to reload all the time"

Answer (score 0):

It's a mechanism to communicate with webserver (backend) without refreshing the whole page. :)

But I believe this site is not a good place to ask these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

"A way of updating a web page in sections, instead of all at once."

Answer (score 0):

It's a technology that allows you to download only select portions of the web page, providing a faster and less disruptive page update.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to AJAX, if you need PEN, you must have to buy PAPER and other things which you already have.

In AJAX, you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A technique which escape your server from extra burden and fasten your responses